# Extracting save data to rosbag in signal present

Tags: python, ros

I need to collect tactile sensor data only I needed. (Tactile sensor mounted to the gripper when gripper holding a wire I need to collect data) using python

I need to collect the data the only event occurs. For example, if I'm going to collect data for the tactile sensor. But I need to collect data once tactile sensor + gripper holding wire I need to collect data. and when it releases I don't need to collect data.

from "rosbag record tactile" this will collect all the data until I stop recording. But I need to get them when gripper holding wire only. Because I need to identify the pattern of different positions of the wire and give that data to ANN for further works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what you want, but I think you want to record two things: the tactile data/msgs (your `rosbag record tactile`), but you also want to *record when the gripper is holding the wire*. If you know *when* the gripper is holding the wire, you can filter all the `tactile` messages by *time* (there should be a [std_msgs/Header](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html)), so you only get the ones where it is holding the wire. I don't know how you plan to modify that to your ANN, but that should be a start.

If you want more help, you'll have to add more information about your setup.